# Illustrator Variables XML file specs - can I define text formatting from XML?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, page-layout, xml

I'm trying to generate lots of files by dynamically loading texts inside of a template. The layout I'm going for is 2 threaded textboxes for 2 columns, and the text is made of title, paragraph, title, paragraph. Like this:

[image: Illustrator variable text box - desired formatting]
The textboxes are bound to an Illustrator variable named Textbox, and my XML looks like this:

```xml
<variableSets  xmlns="&ns_vars;">
  <variableSet  varSetName="binding1" locked="none">
    <variables>
      <variable  varName="Textbox" category="&ns_flows;" trait="textcontent"></variable>
    </variables>
    <v:sampleDataSets  xmlns:v="&ns_vars;" xmlns="&ns_custom;">
      <v:sampleDataSet  dataSetName="1">
      <Textbox>
        <p>Variable-length title</p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet etc. etc. etc.
        </p>
        <p> </p>
        <p>Second variable-length title</p>
        <p>
          Ad delectus in, consequuntur eligendi incidunt etc. etc. etc.
        </p>
      </Textbox>
      </v:sampleDataSet>
    </v:sampleDataSets>
  </variableSet>
</variableSets>
```

When I import this the whole paragraph is the same style, as it's only using `<p>` tags. No differentiation for title.
I thought I could simply write `<h1>Title</h1>` for this but have found that Illustrator won't parse this.

How can I make this textbox have different formatting?

I would create different separate textboxes for titles, but where to place them? I never know where they will show up vertically, that's determined by the amount of paragraph text in each data set. The title itself could wrap on 2 lines as well.

Comment: Not easily, but you can do this inDesign quite painlessly.

Comment: I think it's impossible without a post-population processing script which could match and process special characters that you'd have to also feed into the text. You could write your own tags with a name of the character style to wrap some text in, and use a script which applies this named style and afterwards removes all such tags from the body of the text.

Comment: @Silly-V Like joojaa was mentioning above, this sounds like the InDesign workflow, where you can just use _GREP Find_ to identify the titles, apply the styles and remove the tags. An Illustrator script would of course be a good addition to the toolchain here.

Comment: Yea, if you're able to use Indesign, it's just a native feature of being able to assign a variable to a stretch of text - you wouldn't need to really do anything else than have titles, etc, as separate variables.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for Illustrator? It would be soooooo helpful!

Comment: @AndrewSwift Nope. I think the way to go for Illustrator would be to develop a script, and alter your text to mark it up like Markdown's `## Heading 2` or `{{.paragraph-style-a}} Bla bla`, which then the script searches for using regular expressions... Quite involved, and I'm too slow at scripting Illustrator to tackle it right now.

Comment: Thanks. I do a lot of Illustrator scripting, and that's a great solution, should have thought of it. I think I'll do a markdown interpreter!